# Custom side menu question & active sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I am trying to create a custom side menu that changes depending on what sheet I am on so the side menu is relevant to what I am on.

I've attempted doing some code to do a tactic where depending on what sheet I am on, the script will choose the correct html file I want it to use.

My issue is with my attempt on function SidebarChooser(), where I've looked at if query's and I can't see what is wrong with mine? (I do intend to add more IF's depending on what you say/advise me to do)

```
function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
 .createMenu('Sidebar').addItem('Open', 'openSidebar').addToUi();
}

function SidebarChooser() {

  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('sidebar');
  if (sheet == '1') {


SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(html);

  }

}

function openSidebar() {
var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('sidebar');
SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(html);
}

function Warehouse(){
 var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet() 
 var s=ss.getSheetByName("GoodsInPlus")
 var row=s.getActiveCell().getRow()
 var column=1
 s.getRange(row, column).activate()
}
function order(){
 var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet() 
 var s=ss.getSheetByName("2")
 var row=s.getActiveCell().getRow()
 var column=1
 s.getRange(row, column).activate()
}
function stu(){
 var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet() 
 var s=ss.getSheetByName("UI idea")
 var row=s.getActiveCell().getRow()
 var column=1
 s.getRange(row, column).activate()
}
function merlin(){
 var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet() 
 var s=ss.getSheetByName("Sheet9")
 var row=s.getActiveCell().getRow()
 var column=1
 s.getRange(row, column).activate()
}

function enterName(name){
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
 var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('1')
 sheet.getRange("A3").setValue(name) 
}

function enterClient(client){
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
 var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('1')
 sheet.getRange("E3").setValue(client)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your script is comparing a Sheet object to a literal on the following code line

```
if (sheet == '1') {
```

Replace it by

```
if (sheet.getName() == '1') {
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. :) I looked at loads of examples and didn't see that! :)